# Can a QXYSeries* object have its points replaced with QQueue<QPointF>?

Tags: qt, qml

I have been following the [QML Oscilloscope](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtcharts-qmloscilloscope-example.html) example to create a dynamically updated graph of points, so far I managed to update the points with a `QVector<QPointF> points` being passed into the `replace()` function on my `QXYSeries * xySeries` object:

`xySeries->replace(points);`

However, I would like to use a `QQueue<QPointF>` if possible, so I can update the values at the beginning of the queue and remove old ones from the end of the queue faster than then vector. I want to avoid using `append()`since it's less efficient.

Does anyone know if this is possible?

Comment: I'm not at all sure that replacing data is faster the appending it. Anyway, you have to provide [mcve] so that we can understand exactly what is meant